# Qthread isn't working Not returning signals

Tags: python, multithreading, pyqt, pyqt5, qthread

i have this WorkerSignals class which used to connect signals with the Qthread class worker, `SaveToExcel()` is a function that i used to run in Qthread.

```
class WorkerSignals(QObject):
    finished = pyqtSignal()
    error = pyqtSignal(tuple)
    result = pyqtSignal(object)
    progress = pyqtSignal(int)

    
class Worker(QThread):
    def __init__(self,query,filename,choices,fileExtension,iterativeornot):
        super(Worker,self).__init__()
        self.signals = WorkerSignals()
        self.query =query
        self.filename = filename
        self.choices = choices
        self.fileExtension = fileExtension
        self.iterativeornot =iterativeornot
   

    @pyqtSlot()
    def run(self):
         
        try:
            SaveToExcel(self.query,self.filename,self.choices,self.fileExtension,self.iterativeornot)
        except:
            self.signals.result.emit(1)
        finally:
            self.signals.finished.emit()
```

this is the class that i used to create the Qwidget that has ui

```
class AnotherWindow(QWidget):
    
    def __init__(self,windowname):
        super().__init__()
        self.layout = QVBoxLayout()
        self.label = QLabel()
        self.setWindowTitle(windowname)
        self.setWindowIcon(QIcon(os.path.join(basedir,'./images/import.png')))
        self.setFixedSize(460,440)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.label)
        
        # Query
        self.textinput = QPlainTextEdit()
        self.layout.addWidget(self.textinput)
        
        self.qhboxlayout1 = QHBoxLayout()
        self.IterativeRadiobtn1 = QRadioButton('All Locations')
        self.IterativeRadiobtn2 = QRadioButton('Current Locations')
        self.IterativeRadiobtn2.setChecked(True)
       
        self.qhboxlayout1.addWidget(self.IterativeRadiobtn1)
        self.qhboxlayout1.addWidget(self.IterativeRadiobtn2)
        
        self.layout.addLayout(self.qhboxlayout1)
        
        # Check boxes
        self.c1 = QCheckBox("sc",self)
        self.c2 = QCheckBox("ad",self)
        self.c3 = QCheckBox("sr",self)
        self.c4 = QCheckBox("fc",self)
        
        self.hboxlayoutchoices = QHBoxLayout()
        
    
        #adding checkboxes to layout
        self.checkboxlist = [self.c1,self.c2,self.c3,self.c4]
        for cbox in self.checkboxlist:
            self.hboxlayoutchoices.addWidget(cbox)
        self.layout.addLayout(self.hboxlayoutchoices)

        # filename 
        self.filename = QLineEdit()
        self.layout.addWidget(self.filename)
            
        # Combo box to show the filetype which need to be saved
        self.extensions = QComboBox()
        self.combodict = {'Excel 97-2003 Workbook (*.xls)':'xls','CSV UTF-8 (Comma delimited) (*.csv)':'csv'}
        self.extensions.addItems(self.combodict)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.extensions)
        
        # import button
        self.exportBtn = QPushButton('Import')
        self.layout.addWidget(self.exportBtn)    
        
        #import function when button clicked  
        self.exportBtn.clicked.connect(self.IMPORT)   
        
        #setting layout
        self.setLayout(self.layout)
    
    def RadioButtonCheck(self):
        if self.IterativeRadiobtn1.isChecked():
            return True
        if self.IterativeRadiobtn2.isChecked():
            return False
        
        

    def IMPORT(self):
        self.cboxlist = []
        for cbox in self.checkboxlist:
            if cbox.isChecked():
                self.cboxlist.append(cbox.text())
        
        self.textinput.setReadOnly(True)
        self.filename.setReadOnly(True)
        self.exportBtn.setDisabled(True)  
          
        self.saveFilename = self.filename.text()
        self.text = self.textinput.toPlainText()
        self.inputextension = self.extensions.currentText()
        self.getvalue = self.combodict.get(self.inputextension)
        self.truorfalse = self.RadioButtonCheck()
       
        # self.queryThread = threading.Thread(target=SaveToExcel,args=(self.text,self.saveFilename,self.cboxlist,self.getvalue,self.truorfalse))
        # self.queryThread.start()
        self.worker = Worker(self.text,self.saveFilename,self.cboxlist,self.getvalue,self.truorfalse)
        self.worktherad = QThread()
        self.worker.moveToThread(self.worktherad)
        self.worktherad.started.connect(self.worker.run)
        self.worktherad.finished.connect(self.complete)
        self.worktherad.start()
       
    def complete(self):
        self.msg = QMessageBox()
        self.msg.setWindowTitle("Status")
        self.msg.setText("Import Done")
        self.msg.exec()
        self.textinput.setReadOnly(False)
        self.filename.setReadOnly(False)
        self.exportBtn.setDisabled(False)
        self.exportBtn.setText("Import Again")
```

but when i click the import button the function won't run and just do nothing, I don't have a good knowledge about Qthreading but when i use the python default `threading` the function will run and import the datas. Still i don't have good clear idea about how to implent the Qthreading for the `SaveToExcel` function.

Comment: First of all, QThread inherits from QObject, so making an inner "signal" object is pointless, just add the signals to your subclass. Then, creating a QThread and moving it to another QThread is again pointless, just use *that* instance. Finally, remove the `finished` signal, as QThread already has it and will emit it when `run()` returns. Last thing: only constants should have names with all caps; since `import` is a protected keyword, just use a *better* and more descriptive name, like `importExcel`.

Comment: i did as you says it works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
self.worker = Worker(self.text,self.saveFilename,self.cboxlist,self.getvalue,self.truorfalse)
```

in this line you should probably pass the parent field and you should accept the parent field in `Worker` `__init__` method and pass it in `super` call
(so the thread will automatically destroyed once it's parent object is deleted)

and the `Worker` class is already a `QThread` you do not need to create another `QThread` and move it..

you should just run the `self.worker` by `self.worker.start()`

and don't forget to connect those `Worker` signals to valid `pyqtSlot` and if possible then connect those before starting the `self.worker` thread

Updated Code Snippet

```
        self.worker = Worker(parent, self.text,self.saveFilename,self.cboxlist,self.getvalue,self.truorfalse) # Accept parent in __init__ method of Worker
        self.worktherad.finished.connect(self.complete)
        self.worktherad.start()
```

And also make `complete` function a `pyqtSlot` by adding decorator `QtCore.pyqtSlot()`

Comment: this works well but when i terminated `self.worker.terminate()` the finished result is emiting and `self.complete` is executed how do i kill the qthread when user closes the window?

Comment: You do not need to kill the thread and don't terminate the QThread unless until necessary, just wait for it to finish using `self.worker.wait()` method

Comment: what will happen if i close the window and the thread is still running. so when the user clicks the window close button the thread need to be stopped. how can  i implement that?

Comment: take the `close` event of the main application and override it's behavior

Comment: `def closeEvent(self,event):
        self.close = QMessageBox.question(self,"QUIT","Are you sure want to stop process?",
                                     QMessageBox.Yes|QMessageBox.No)
        if self.close == QMessageBox.Yes:
                if self.worker is None:
                    event.accept()
                elif self.worker.isRunning():
                    self.worker.terminate()
                    event.accept()
           
        else:
            event.ignore()`

Comment: i allready have overide the behavior. rather than terminating the qthread i want to quit the Qthread without returning finished signal and executing the `self.complete`

Comment: then you can disconnect the `finished` signal first and then wait for the thread to complete

Comment: what if i not closing the window and want the process to be finished and the qmessagebox to be pop up and say import done or when the user close the window pop up the qmessagebox and say import terminated etc.

Comment: You can display any message you want to display for respective events, the problem here is to gracefully stop the qthread which can be done using wait() method and disconnecting signals

Comment: Making the `complete` a slot is not necessary. The last code is also wrong, as it still refers to `worktherad`.

Comment: how can i implement that? rather than making complete slot?